# Get data from object as string without metadata

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a report in powershell, given a list of groups it should output the members of that group, I tried:

```
$members = [string]::Join(",", (
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Recursive |
        Select-Object -Property name
))
```

But I get:

```
@(name=abc)\t@(name=def)\t@(name=ghi)...
```

Piping the output through `Out-String`

```
$members=[string]::Join(",", (
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Recursive |
        Select-Object -Property name | Out-String
))
```

resulted in:

```
name
--------------
abc   
def
ghi
...
```

But I just want the text values without the metadata (not too bothered about the field seperators) e.g.

```
abc,def,ghi...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$members = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $grp -Recursive | Select-Object name).name -join ','
```

With Select-Object -Property name you're only getting back the values for the property "name" but you still have to retrieve the values of the property.